# Store a list of objects without duplicates in a database DAO

Tags: java, android

How do I store a list of objects without duplicates in a database?
I have my database DAO:

```
@Dao
public interface UserDAO {
    @Query("select*from User")
    List<User> getAll();
    @Insert
    void insertAll(User...users);
}
```

User class have:

```
@Entity(indices = {@Index(value = {"name"}, unique = true)})
public class User {
@ColumnInfo(name="name")
public String name;
@ColumnInfo(name="surname")
public String surname;
@PrimaryKey @NonNull
public String uid;
```

I recover some users from the school server and I have duplicate users and I want store some Users without duplicates in my database DAO:

```
Model_user.getInstance(activity.getApplicationContext()).addUser(
                                        new User(
                                                uid,
                                                name,
                                                surname));
```

I want store for example:`["11","Jenny","McCart"],["12","Mark","McBack"]` instead I store:`["11","Jenny","McCart"],["12","Mark","McBack"],["11","Jenny","McCart"]`

Comment: Your uid is primary key. you should get DataIntegrityViolationException for second duplicate record insert. may be you can first remove duplicates from your list then insert. Or use Set instead of list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think for your case you've to use onConflictStrategy when inserting the code. So whenever a new entry with same uid is made, room will replace it

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void insertAll(User...users);
```